# Can you tell if you're being squelched?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone there is a function to "squelch" an opponent (right click on their hero), which makes them unable to emote, or at least makes you unable to see them emote. In practice it silence them. Can a "squelched one" (it sounds almost lovecraftian) tell if it was given the silence treatment or not?

[image: Squelching Shamans]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't know that you've been squelched. But if you see them hover (the little glow) over you, there's a good chance they did. [Source](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/12504871253)